# Simple counter loop in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

Looking through the docs (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/), all the examples seem to be showing using `for` loops to iterate through lists.

I just want to have a simple numeric iterator, i.e. `for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)`.

Is this possible in Jinja ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [range](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#range) function to generate a list of integers. So for example:

```
{% for i in range(10) %}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Results in:

```
0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9
```